# Get distinct records with multiple columns without grouping using MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a dataset

```
CREATE TABLE `dailytrades` (
  `dailytrades_date` date NOT NULL,
  `dailytrades_symbol` varchar(125) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dailytrades_qty` int(12) DEFAULT '0',
  `dailytrades_price` float(12,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `dailytrades_price_qualifier` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dailytrades_amt` float(12,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `dailytrades_amt_qualifier` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

with the following rows:-

```
+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----------+-----+
| 2019-12-24 | SLES | 250  | 20   | XCD | 5,000.00  | XCD |
+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----------+-----+
| 2020-01-09 | BOSV | 50   | 6.75 | XCD | 337.5     | XCD |
+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----------+-----+
| 2020-01-13 | CWKN | 443  | 3.5  | XCD | 1,550.50  | XCD |
+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----------+-----+
| 2020-01-13 | CWKN | 117  | 3.5  | XCD | 409.5     | XCD |
+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----------+-----+
| 2020-01-13 | SKNB | 3114 | 3    | XCD | 9,342.00  | XCD |
+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----------+-----+
| 2020-01-13 | SKNB | 4861 | 3    | XCD | 14,583.00 | XCD |
+----------+------+------+------+-----+-----------+-----+
```

I'm trying to retrieve distinct values in the second column that are the "latest"( dataset is sorted by the first column in ascending order) along with the rest of the other columns' values.

Using GROUP BY seems to have unexpected results which do not reflect the required results and DISTINCT will try to apply itself to all columns listed which is not what I want.

How can I get the distinct values of the 2nd column while retrieving all columns and defaulting to the "latest" based on the ascending order?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: For CWKN & SKNB, Which record you want to appear? As both have the same dates.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai it is assumed that the "order of entry" would determine which record/ row is the most recent.

Comment: @KendallARNEAUD Unfortunately, that's a meaningless assumption

Comment: @KendallARNEAUD, So as per your assumptions, Which should remain in the output so both row have the same date and since there is not time how would you determine, which row inserted first.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai the datasource is from an external 3rd party application for which as one of its defined rule is to enter real time information as it is received from oldest to newest. I'm boggled that it doesn't attribute a proper date timestamp but alas I am just the messenger

Answer (score 1):

If your date column have time part also, But you didn't share it here, You may try with below query which joins the symbol with the maximum dates -

```
SELECT `dailytrades_date`,
       `dailytrades_symbol`,
       `dailytrades_qty`,
       `dailytrades_price`,
       `dailytrades_price_qualifier`,
       `dailytrades_amt`,
       `dailytrades_amt_qualifier`
FROM `dailytrades` dt
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(`dailytrades_date`) `max_date`,
                   `dailytrades_symbol`
            FROM `dailytrades`
            GROUP BY `dailytrades_symbol`) mdt ON dt.`dailytrades_date` = mdt.`max_date`
```

Since you mention you dont have any time part so above query will not work perfectly. So to make every row unique in inner join inline view, I am picking `dailytrades_qty` column also.

```
SELECT `dailytrades_date`,
       `dailytrades_symbol`,
       `dailytrades_qty`,
       `dailytrades_price`,
       `dailytrades_price_qualifier`,
       `dailytrades_amt`,
       `dailytrades_amt_qualifier`
FROM `dailytrades` dt
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(`dailytrades_date`) `max_date`,
                   `dailytrades_symbol`,
                   MAX(`dailytrades_qty`) `dailytrades_qty`
            FROM `dailytrades`
            GROUP BY `dailytrades_symbol`) mdt ON dt.`dailytrades_date` = mdt.`max_date`
                                               AND DT.`dailytrades_qty` = mdt.`dailytrades_qty`
```

Comment: Odd to select a column and then do nothing with it

Comment: @Strawberry, Which column you mean?

Comment: Honestly this is an acceptable choice as it is what I'm currently implementing....however I'm gonna be using a separate table to implement an auto incremented id and use that in the inner join.